# How to update React component when async prop promise resolves?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, properties, async-await

Lets say I have a component that renders a `PivotGrid` component. This `PivotGrid` takes some data, an array of objects.

```
function My_component(props) {
    return <PivotGrid dataSource={props.data} />
}
```

However, the `data` prop that I want to pass in is the result of an async function.

```
const get_data = async () => {
    return await o(url, options).get('foo').query({})
}

ReactDOM.render(<My_component data={get_data()}/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

What happens is that the component renders before the promise from `get_data()` is resolved, and the PivotGrid has no data.

What I would like to happen is for the component to re-render when the promise resolves and actually returns data. I've tried variations of React's `useState()` to treat `props.data` as a state variable, so that when the promise returns the state would change the the component would update. But this has not worked yet.

```
const [gridData, setGridData] = useState(props.data);
props.data.then((r) => {
    setGridData(props.data)
})
```

Attempts like the above all fail. What is the best way to achieve this functionality, where the component re-renders when `prop.data` resolves and actually holds the data I want?

Comment: Check out `useEffect` https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: You can call `get_data` function inside `My_component` instead of passing the data through props and there you can control the rendering of the component either using hooks or transforming it into React Component.

Comment: Thanks for the response @SimoMatavulj. I want to pass this data as a prop so that this component is reusable.

Comment: You can create a wrapper that will be fetching data and passing it to your `My_component`

Answer (score 1):

Using hooks and the container component for My_component should work.

my-component-container.js:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import My_component from './my-component'

export default () => {
   const [data, setData] = useState(null)
   useEffect(async () => {
     const fetchData = async () => {
         const result = await o(url, options).get('foo').query({})

         setData(result);
     };

    fetchData();
   }, [])

   return <My_component dataSource={data} />
}
```

In your entry point:

```
import My_component_container from './my-component-container'

ReactDOM.render(<My_component_container />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I've tried this and it doesn't quite work but I think it is a step in the right direction. Creating a container component in this fashion throws an error, saying that useEffect can't return an async function, and that the proper way is to write an async function inside useEffect and call it right away. This still does not work, however...

Comment: @jpc you're right, I updated the answer with your comment in mind

Answer (score 0):

Why not change to a stateful component like below

```
class My_component extends React.Component {
   state = {};

   componentDidMount(){
     this.get_data()
   }

   get_data = async () => {
     const data = await o(url, options).get('foo').query({});
     this.setState({ data });
   }

   render() {
      const { data } = this.state;
      return <PivotGrid dataSource={data} />
   }
```

}

Comment: Due to the nature of this project it must be a functional component. I also have to pass the data in as a prop as this component has to be reusable and will take data from different sources.