# How to re-render React Component when promise resolves? | How to block render until data loads?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, azure

I’ve tried to update a functional component that points to an `azure-devops-ui/Filter`. I am using `azure-devops-extension-sdk` that returns an async response, in order to use this component:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-devops/components/filter
inside a WorkItem on Azure DevOps

I’ve already code with both a class-based and function component using `this.state`/`componentDidMount` and `useState`/`useEffect` respectively. I followed [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57117701/how-to-update-react-component-when-async-prop-promise-resolves).

However, I only can re-render the state. The UI component neither in a class nor in a functional component updates when the state is updated.

There are my two versions of the code, both them wait for the response and successfully update state. However, neither will wait for render of the UI.

General Component:

```
import {
    IWorkItemChangedArgs,
    IWorkItemFieldChangedArgs,
    IWorkItemFormService,
    IWorkItemLoadedArgs,
    WorkItemTrackingServiceIds,
  } from "azure-devops-extension-api/WorkItemTracking";

import * as React from "react";
import * as SDK from "azure-devops-extension-sdk";

import { Header } from "azure-devops-ui/Header";
import { Page } from "azure-devops-ui/Page";

import { Filter, getKeywordFilterItem } from "azure-devops-ui/Filter";
import { IListBoxItem } from "azure-devops-ui/ListBox";
import { AggregateItemProvider } from "azure-devops-ui/Utilities/AggregateItemProvider";
import {
    Filter as FilterStore,
    FILTER_CHANGE_EVENT,
    IFilterState
} from "azure-devops-ui/Utilities/Filter";
import { GroupedItemProvider } from "azure-devops-ui//Utilities/GroupedItemProvider";
import { groupedItems, groups, statusItems } from "./data";
        export class WorkItemComponent extends React.Component<{} & ExtendedProps, any> {

    private provider: AggregateItemProvider<IListBoxItem>;

    private filterStore = new FilterStore();

    private textoStore = "second";

    private groupedProvider = new GroupedItemProvider([], [], true);
    private filterItems = [
        getKeywordFilterItem(this.filterStore),
        { name: "Status", id: "status", items: statusItems, filterItemKey: "status" },
        {
            name: "Group Items",
            id: "groupItems",
            items: this.groupedProvider,
            filterItemKey: "groupItems"
        }
    ];

    constructor(props: {}) {
        super(props);
        this.provider = new AggregateItemProvider<IListBoxItem>();
        this.groupedProvider.push(...groupedItems);
        this.groupedProvider.pushGroups(...groups);
        this.provider.push(statusItems);
        this.provider.push(this.groupedProvider);


        if(this.props.pdata==="first")
        this.filterStore = new FilterStore(
          {defaultState: {    groupItems: {        value: [this.props.pdata,this.textoStore]    }}} 
          );
          else
          this.filterStore = new FilterStore(
            {defaultState: {    groupItems: {        value: [this.textoStore,this.props.pdata,]    }}} 
            );


          this.filterStore.subscribe(this.onFilterChanged, FILTER_CHANGE_EVENT);


        this.state = {
            //currentState: ""
            currentState: JSON.stringify(this.filterStore.getState(), null, 4)
        };

    }

    public render():JSX.Element {

        return (
            <Page className="sample-hub flex-grow">
                <Header title="Filter" />
                <div className="page-content">
                <Filter 
                    filterStore={this.filterStore}
                    filterItems={this.filterItems}
                    items={this.provider}
                />
                    <div style={{ marginTop: "16px" }} className="monospaced-text">
                        <span>Current state:</span>
                        <span>{this.state.currentState}</span>
                        <span>{this.props.pdata}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Page>
        );
    }

    private onFilterChanged = (changedState: IFilterState) => {
        this.setState({
            currentState: JSON.stringify(this.filterStore.getState(), null, 4)
        });
        this.onFilterChangedExtended(JSON.stringify(this.filterStore.getState(), null, 4))
    };

    private async onFilterChangedExtended(estadoActual: string) {
        const workItemFormService = await SDK.getService<IWorkItemFormService>(
          WorkItemTrackingServiceIds.WorkItemFormService
        );

        workItemFormService.setFieldValue(SDK.getConfiguration().witInputs.FieldName, estadoActual);

      }
```

The first Caller with useState and useEffect inside a Functional component:

```
        import { WorkItemComponent } from "./WorkItemComponent";

  const WorkItemFilterAsync: React.FC = props => {

    let respuestaAsync="";

    const [data, setData] = React.useState<string>('');
    React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchdata = async() =>{
      const result = await fngetFieldName()

         setData(result);

    }      
      // Execute the created function directly
      fetchdata();

    }, []);


    async function fngetFieldName(): Promise<string> {
      const workItemFormService = await SDK.getService<IWorkItemFormService>(
        WorkItemTrackingServiceIds.WorkItemFormService
      );

      const respuesta = workItemFormService.getFieldValue(SDK.getConfiguration().witInputs.FieldName);
      respuestaAsync = (await respuesta).toString();
      return JSON.stringify(respuesta);
    }
  return <WorkItemComponent pdata={data}/>
}
export default WorkItemFilterAsync;
```

And the second caller with componentDidMount on a class:

```
import {
    IWorkItemChangedArgs,
    IWorkItemFieldChangedArgs,
    IWorkItemFormService,
    IWorkItemLoadedArgs,
    WorkItemTrackingServiceIds,
  } from "azure-devops-extension-api/WorkItemTracking";


import * as React from "react";
import { showRootComponent } from "../../Common";
import * as SDK from "azure-devops-extension-sdk";

import { WorkItemComponent } from "./WorkItemComponent";

//const WorkItemComponent = React.lazy (() => import('./WorkItemComponent'));


class WorkItemFilter extends React.Component{
    state = {
        externalData: false,
      };

      public componentDidMount() {
          this.onLoadExtended();
    }

    render():JSX.Element {

            return(

                <div className="page-content">
                    {this.state.externalData ? <WorkItemComponent pdata="first"/> : <WorkItemComponent pdata="third"/>}
                </div>

            );
        }


        private async onLoadExtended() {
            const workItemFormService = await SDK.getService<IWorkItemFormService>(
              WorkItemTrackingServiceIds.WorkItemFormService
            );

            let varaux = workItemFormService.getFieldValue(SDK.getConfiguration().witInputs.FieldName);

            if ((await varaux).toString()!=="")
            {

                this.setState({
                    externalData: true,
                });

            }

          }


}


  showRootComponent(<WorkItemFilter />);
```

This is the parent component:

```
export function showRootComponent(component: React.ReactElement<any>) {
    ReactDOM.render(component, document.getElementById("root"));
}
```

Configuration for the Azure Dev Ops Extension (`azure-devops-extension.json`):

```
{
    "contributions": [
        {
            "id": "work-item-filter",
            "type": "ms.vss-work-web.work-item-form-control",
            "description": "Custom Filter",
            "targets": [
                "ms.vss-work-web.work-item-form"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "name": "BHD Filter",
                "uri": "dist/WorkItemFilter/WorkItemFilter.html",
                "height": 600,
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "id":"FieldName",
                        "name": "Select the field for this control.",
                        "type": "WorkItemField",
                        "properties": {
                            "workItemFieldTypes": ["String", "PlainText", "HTML"]
                        },
                        "validation": {
                            "dataType": "String",
                            "isRequired": true
                        }
```

[image: UI issue 1 without updated state]

I also tried putting the `ReactDOM.render` inside a browser event, but I cannot do that because the UI extension needs a field to save the data:

[image: UI issue 2 with refresh]

Comment: What do you mean by "But I only can re-render the state, not the UI component neither in a class nor in a functional component." In React, the render function will get called whenever state or props are updated. It'll be re-rendered. In a functional component, the component will get updated when state or props are updated. The state is from `useState` hook. I don't know TypeScript well, but I think you want to store the data from the promise using the `useState` hook. Get the data in the `useEffect` and set the state from the `useState` hook. It will automatically re-render.

Comment: Dear @technogeek1995 :  Although  I Put `<Filter filterStore={this.state.filterStore} `; changing the state, works or update only on `<span>{this.state.currentState}</span>` not in the <Filter>. Still with a Button and onClick event I changed the `state.filterStore` but Filter never updates this values or auto check any value, just it works like the image once on the constructor.

Comment: Dear @technogeek1995: Is like ReactDOM.render never waits for the response of the Async function `workItemFormService.getFieldValue` on both cases, even with **Lazy and Suspense**

Comment: I don’t have experience with Lazy and Suspense. However, the render function is non-blocking. It will never wait for the value of a promise. It will only re-render with props or state changes. Thus, when you get data, you need to set state so the component will re-render with the new state and update the value. Then you’ll see the value updating not just with the onClick, but when the data is received by the promise. I can formalize this into a simple vanilla JS answer for you if that would help explain it better?

Comment: Yes Please, dear @technogeek1995

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing a functional react component is simple with the new React Hooks. In the example below, I'm using `useState` and `useEffect`. The `useState` hook is synonymous with `this.state/this.setState` in a class-based React component. The `useEffect` hook is similar to `componentDidMount`+`componentDidUpdate`. It also is capable of being `componentDidUnmount`.

The way the code will execute is from top to bottom. Because it's functional, it will run through once and render with the default state set at the argument to `useState`. It will not block on getting data from the API in the `useEffect` function. Thus, you need to be able to handle loading without having data. Anytime `props.apiConfig` or `props.id` changes, the component will re-render and all the `useEffect` again. **It will only call `useEffect` if `props.apiConfig` and `props.id` do change after first run.** The only nasty part is that `useEffect` cannot be an `async` function, so you have to call the function `getDataWrapper` without using `await`. When the data is received by the API, it will store the data in `state`, which will trigger a re-render of the component.

To Summarize:

1. Render once with default state

   - Call `useEffect`, which calls `getDataWrapper`
   - return component with initial values in `useState`
2. Once data is received by the API in the `useEffect`/`getDataWrapper` function, set the state via `setState` & set `isLoading` to `false`
3. Re-render the component with updated value that `setState` now contains

   - Avoid the `useEffect` control path since the values in the second argument of `useEffect` have not changed. (eg: `props.apiConfig` & `props.id`).

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { getDataFromAPI } from './api';

const MyComponent = (props) => {

  const [state, useState] = useState({
    isLoading: true,
    data: {}
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const getDataWrapper = async () => {
      const response = await getDataFromAPI(apiConfig, props.id);
      setState({
        isLoading: false,
        data: response
      });
    });

    getDataWrapper();
  }, [props.apiConfig, props.id]);


  if(state.isLoading) { return <div>Data is loading from API...</div>

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(state.data, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: Thanks, I tested again but it works for simple HTMLs Tags, like: 
<span>{this.state.currentState}</span>
<span>{this.props.pdata}</span>
but not for: azure-devops-ui/Filter

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work for `azure-devops-ui/Filter`? Is there no data in the variable you're trying to output via JSX?

Comment: I've tried also with this.state.filterStore 
`<Filter 
                    filterStore={this.state.filterStore}
                    filterItems={this.filterItems}
                    items={this.provider}
                />`
But is updated only on simples HTMLs Tags like <span> not inside the UI: Filter, like in the image of my Question, the state is Updated, but not the UI, just on Filter.

Comment: Does the data you’re receiving from the API match the format for the Azure Dev Ops filter’s props? Obviously, since you’re getting it to update correctly in normal HTML fields, something is wrong either with how you’re passing data into the Filter component or with the Filter component itself? Have you verified that what you’re passing in matches the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-devops/components/dropdown) for the filter component?

Comment: When update the WIT I’ve got the items pre saved on a field, in order to precheck during the onload of the WIT with the async function: 
`workItemFormService.getFieldValue(SDK.getConfiguration().witInputs.FieldName);`
To precheck the elements on the Filter UI using the constructor, (I’ve also tried an onClick action): 
`this.filterStore = new FilterStore(
          {defaultState: { groupItems: { value: [this.props.pdata,this.textoStore] }}} 
          );` 
Also I’ve tried with
`this.state = {
            FilterStoreAux: FilterStore
        };`
using:
this.state.FilterStoreAux`